# Symfony joining tables

Tags: symfony

I'm completely new to **Symfony** and I'm struggling with the query builder.

I have card entity and transaction entity in manytomany relation.

```
card entity: (id, card_number, code)
transaction entity: (id, amount, source, destination)
card_transaction: (card_id, transaction_id)
```

I want to get all the transactions that have a given card number.

Comment: Can you add any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'd typically need to see the source for both of those entity classes.

Have you made a repository class for the `CardTransaction` entity yet? You could create this to have a reusable query as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

class CardTransactionRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findByCardNumber(int $cardNumber): array
    {
        if ($cardNumber < 1) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Card ID invalid.");
        }

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("ct")
            ->leftJoin("ct.card", "c")
            ->andWhere("c.cardNumber = :cardNumber")
            ->setParameter("cardNumber", $cardNumber)
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

That being said what you're doing is such a simple query/operation you shouldn't need a query builder to do it. This is precisely what entity classes make easy, including Doctrine's `ArrayCollection` class.

If you're just doing this in a controller or view and have already loaded the `Card` entity you don't need a query in a repository class. Just iterate `$card->getCardTransactions()` assuming you've created the appropriate data accessor functions in `Card`. -- Then again, without seeing the `Card` and `CardTransaction` entity sources I couldn't tell you exactly what method names you have (or need).

You can retrieve a `Card` entity by its `card_number` property in a controller as follows:

```
$card = $this->getRepository(Card::class)->findOneByCardNumber($cardNumber);
```

Ideally you should check it exists too though kind of like this:

```
if (!($cardNumber = intval($cardNumber))) { // Do something better to validate the card number that has been specified, e.g. a `preg_match()`
    throw $this->createNotFoundException("Card not specified.");
}

if (!($card = $this->getRepository(Card::class)->findOneByCardNumber($cardNumber))) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException("Card not found.");
}
```